# sql get a number whose range is another number

Tags: c#, sql

I have a column of price breaks and need to find the row that contains a certain quantity. It is set up like this:

```
id | MinimumQuantity | Price
-----------------------------------
1  |        1        |    10
1  |        10       |    20
1  |        25       |    30
```

...and the quantity could be any number. So, if the quantity is 1 I would need to get the Price 10 (1-10), if the quantity is 15 I would need to get the Price 20 (10-25) and if the quantity is 100 I would need to get Price 30 (25+). So far I have:

```
select Price from myTable where MinimumQuantity >= @myQuantity and id = @myID
```

...but of course this doesn't return 25+, it seems like it should be simple but I'm stumped. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you mean: "if the quantity is 15 I would need to get the Price 20"?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I'll change the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is proper query for mysql:

```
SELECT `Price` from `myTable`
WHERE @myQuantity >= `MinimumQuantity` and `id` = @myID
ORDER BY `MinimumQuantity` ASC
LIMIT 1
```

for sql server:

```
SELECT top 1 [Price] from [myTable]
WHERE @myQuantity >= [MinimumQuantity] and [id] = @myID
ORDER BY [MinimumQuantity] ASC
```

Comment: Thanks Lashane, it works perfectly if I change the order to DESC.